# Using HttpClient.GetAsync to call Web API seems to hang

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm working on a proof of concept prototype.
I have Asp.Net C# web form (Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.5) page. On a button click I do something like this:

```
List<Blog> blogs = null;
protected void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...;

    switch (int.Parse(rblDataSource.SelectedValue))
    {
        //...;

        case 4:
            RunAsyncBlogs().Wait();

            break;

        default:
            blogs = localGetter.GetBlogs();
            break;
    }

    //...;
}
```

RunAsyncBlogs looks like this:

```
static async Task RunAsyncBlogs()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/wapiDemo/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Blogs");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            List<Blog> thisBlogList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Blog>>();
            var cnt = thisBlogList.Count();
        }

    }
}
```

The code stops at the response = await client.GetAsync call. When I say it stops, the debugger acts like the request has ended, but the browser is still waiting.

If I run a console app (I copy and paste the RunAsync() method into it) which calls the Web API the same way, I get my data. So, I believe the Web API app is responding as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
 RunAsyncBlogs().Wait();
```

Is deadlocking your code. It is synchronously blocking your async method call which is trying to marshal back the continuation on to the implicitly captured synchronization context. That is why you [*shouldn't block on async code*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

```
protected async void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Other stuff
   await RunAsyncBlogs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have to nested `async` methods. `RunAsyncBlogs` and `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Blog>>();` inside of it.

Adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` at the end of following line will prevent your code from hanging:

```
var thisBlogList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Blog>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, even though this will solve blocking, code will still execute synchronously, because of the `Wait()` call in `btnLoadData_Click` method.

Switching to asynchronous execution, as already suggested is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your button click event needs to be async.

```
protected async void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...;

    switch (int.Parse(rblDataSource.SelectedValue))
    {
        //...;

        case 4:
            await RunAsyncBlogs();

            break;

        default:
            blogs = localGetter.GetBlogs();
            break;
    }

    //...;
}
```

See this post on dealing with blocking issues with async.

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Is a Web Application with VS2013 with WEbAPi and MVC 
In MVC I have I link to this:

```
public JsonResult GetWithHttpClient()
{

Employee employee = null;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(path);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Employees/12345").Result;

    //the IsSuccessStatusCode property is false if the status is an error code. 
    //All the error: {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Pragma: no-cache  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRkFCSU9fQ09ESUNFXE15RXhhbXBsZVxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcV2ViQXBwbGljYXRpb24xXGFwaVxFbXBsb3llZXNcMTIzNDU=?=  Cache-Control: no-cache  Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 14:47:03 GMT  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  Content-Length: 61  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  Expires: -1}}
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            employee = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>().Result;               

    }
}

return Json (employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

The WebApi is called EmployeesController. And I have this method:

```
public Employee Get(int id)
{
return list.First(e => e.Id == id);
}
```